# Android EditText convert string to integer error

Tags: android

My application forced closed when I try to convert the editText String to integer and I don't know why. I think i'm converting it right.
What supposed to be the problem? Thanks in advance.

```
edX = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.dh);

path.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String holder = edX.getText().toString();
                int a = Integer.parseInt(holder);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }   
        });
```

Comment: where is your logcat?

Comment: I can't copy paste my log cat  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)   at pathfinding.thesis.algorith.PathSetup$1.onClick(PathSetup.java:73)

Comment: follow the below given answers then or delete your question.

Answer (score 2):

Probably getting :

> Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID

Because `Toast makeText` takes `CharSequence` as second parameter.

Use `String.valueOf` to get String representation of int:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
     String.valueOf(a), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Why Down-Vote ? please kindly leave comments with down-vote to improve my answer and for learn .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Modify your toast as below :

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(a), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

Use my code below , It will definetely solve your problem.

```
path.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String holder = edX.getText().toString();
            int a=-1;
            try {
                a = Integer.parseInt(holder);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(a==-1){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "INVALID NUMBER INPUT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{                  
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }   
    });
```

The hack is , Toast class can only accept integer resource ids and string object . I converted int to String :) .